# Android Studio не открывает файлы фрагментного и вершинного шейдеров

Tags: android, android-studio, opengles, glsl

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ansroid Studio(build 144.0) не открывает файлы шейдеров. При этом код компилируется и всё исправно работает(файлы открывал вручную через notepad++). Тема для меня новая, допускаю, что решение элементарное.
Гуглил, всё что нашёл, установить плагин GLSL support. Установил, при создании файла появилось "GLSL Shader", но итог тот же.

[image: GLSL Shader]

Comment: 1.19? Такой не было, а если и была, то в 2015 году.

Comment: Так это просто текстовые файлы? Измените расширение на "txt". Я так делал в учебных примерах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При первой попытке открыть неизвестный тип файла IDEA/Студия предлагает выбор как его открывать, запоминает и больше не предлагает, даже если выбор сделан не правильно.
Теперь придётся править ассоциацию в настройках.
`File->Settings...->Editor->File Types`
В верхнем окошке находим плагин GLSL или какой нам надо, выделяем и в нижнем окошке добавляем `*.glsl`, всё подтверждаем.
[image: настройка ассоциаций]